# How to get java enum ordinal value in MyBatis SELECT query

Tags: mybatis

How to get java enum ordinal value directly in the following SELECT query?

Enum Status

```
package com.enum;

public enum Status {
    A, B, C, D, E;
}
```

Class Aa

```
package com.prj;

import com.enum.Status;

public class Aa {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Status status; // store enum ordinal in table aa
}
```

This following query is not working.

```
<select id="getAaValidIds" resultType="Long">
    SELECT
        aa.id
    FROM
        aa aa
    WHERE
        aa.status = @com.enum.Status$A.ordinal() 
        OR aa.status = @com.enum.Status$B.ordinal() 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OGNL expression with `${}`.

```sql
WHERE
  aa.status = ${@com.enum.Status@A.ordinal()}
  OR aa.status = ${@com.enum.Status@B.ordinal()}
```

---

The below is the original answer.
It incorrectly assumed that the enum is passed as a parameter.

There is a built-in type handler for that.
You can specify `javaType` and `typeHandler` for each parameter. e.g.

```sql
WHERE
  aa.status = #{status,javaType=com.enum.Status,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler}
  OR aa.status = #{status,javaType=com.enum.Status,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler}
```

Or, if you always use this type handler for `Status`, it is better to register it globally in the config.

```xml
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler
    javaType="com.enum.Status"
    handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler" />
</typeHandlers>
```

Then you can just write...

```sql
WHERE
  aa.status = #{status}
  OR aa.status = #{status}
```

Comment: #{status} -> means the status as a parameter? Is it possible to read the enum directly?

Comment: Sorry about my misunderstanding.  Updated the answer.

Comment: ${@com.enum.Status@A.ordinal()} is not working. 
${@com.enum.Status@A.ordinal} is working. 

Thanks @ave

Comment: @Stov Glad to know it worked! Just curious, which version of MyBatis are you using? `ordinal()` worked fine for me with 3.5.1.

Comment: MyBatis v 3.5.0

Comment: One more question please. If I need the enum as a string, Status.A -> "A", how to convert it? ${@com.enum.Status@A.name} returns A, not 'A'.

Comment: @Stov `${}` is a [text substitution](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-), so just add quotes `'${@com.enum.Status@A.name()}'` and it returns `'A'`.

Comment: I will use '${@com.enum.Status@A}'. Thanks @ave